# Is there any difference between "!=" and "!~" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I was trying to play with the operators `!~` and `!=` in below code. But couldn't figure out such any differences. But I have doubt, If not so, why Ruby introduced them?

```
 2 !=3
# => true
 2 !~ 3
# => true
 c= [1,2,3]
# => [1, 2, 3]
 d=[1,4,5]
# => [1, 4, 5]
 c != d
# => true
 c !~ d
# => true
```

Could anyone please help me here by saying if any difference between them ?

Comment: I believe `!~` is used to match a string with a regexp.

Comment: `2 != 2;` => `false` but `2 !~ 2;` => `true`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The `=~` operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-3D-7E) and its negative `!~` are for pattern-matching. It is overridden by [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) and [String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) to provide regular-expression pattern matching, but for numbers it is not implemented. This is why `2 =~ 3` gives `nil`, so `2 !~ 3` is `true`.

Comment: If it is not implemented for numbers fine,then how such `boolean` values are coming>

Comment: means you are saying `2 !~ 3` returning `!nil`?

Comment: @user2060534 Correct.  `a !~ b` basically does does this: `!(a =~ b)`.  So then `2 !~ 3` is actually `!(2 =~ 3)` => `!(nil)` => `true`